# Can't connect to redis on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq with active_job in my rails application. The job currently works but I am unable to get connect to the Redis when deploying to heroku. In heroku I have the RedisToGo addon. When pushing to heroku I get the following error.

#### error

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:331:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
```

#### config/application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
  PasswordAgingJob.perform_later
  SetOffCallJob.perform_later
end
```

#### config/initializers/redis.rb

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/" )
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

#### config/initializers/active_job.rb

```
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set `REDIS_PROVIDER` to the name of the env var with your Redis URL.

Type this: `heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL`.  Restart.

Explained here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#using-an-env-variable

Comment: I have a feeling a few people land here when they also don't have the right worker set up. Mike, do you happen to know how one configures their heroku app such that a worker is ready to go to run Redis?

Answer (score 3):

Setting `REDIS_URL` in `heroku` config help me to resolve:

```
Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
```

Comment: I spent weeks trying to figure this out, tried all kind of solution, but it was that simple! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You must set the `REDISTOGO_URL` on Heroku.

Click on **Settings**, and then **Reveal Config Vars**.

Comment: It seems that it is not set correctly. Is it possible that it is misspelled? Did you set it manually, or change it?

Comment: You may need to do `heroku restart`.

Comment: It was setting using the [heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo)

Answer (score 0):

Setting REDIS_URL to redis://@pike.redistogo.com:10731/ seem to work for me.

Comment: be careful sharing redis urls